# Show More/Less Button but with Divs

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement a show/hide button that will expand a list of divs. What I have works - sort of... it just seems that the height isn't being calculated correctly. I grabbed some canned code that I've used for simple paragraphs, but I now have a div > div situation. I'm assuming what I have is trying to calculate off of a parent `<p>` vs. a `<div>`?

```js
var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

$(".list-body .button").click(function() {

  totalHeight = 0

  $el = $(this);
  $p = $el.parent();
  $up = $p.parent();
  $ps = $up.find("p:not('.show-more')");

  $ps.each(function() {
    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
  });

  $up
    .css({
      "height": $up.height(),
      "max-height": 9999
    })
    .animate({
      "height": totalHeight
    });

  $p.fadeOut();

  return false;

});
```

```css
.list-body {
  max-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-body .show-more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header Info
  </div>
  <div class="list-body">
    <div class="item">
      Item #1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item #2
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      Item #3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item #4
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="show more">
    <a href="#" class="button">Show More</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You say that what you have sort of works. The code you've presented here doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also, don't use hyperlinks just to have something that acts as a JavaScript hook. Hyperlinks are for navigation and those who rely on assistive technologies, like screen readers, will get confused by this. Any visual element supports a `click` event. So, just make the paragraph that holds "Show More" the clickable thing and eliminate the anchor.

Comment: If you have an example of the effect you're after visually, I'm betting we could show you how to accomplish it cleaner and without js/jquery.

Comment: @ScottMarcus not sure what you're talking about. That doesn't seem to be applicable to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ChrisW. trying to do something like this:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ReadMoreFade/

I made a JSFiddle that shows where I'm stuck: https://jsfiddle.net/6shr138a/